# Watermark align content to the extreme left

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have made a watermark that is aligned to left of the main content in my website. While I am unable to adjust it properly due to some missing CSS attributes.
This is the current look of website:
[image]

But when I try to minimise the screen, or go to mobile mode, this watermark is covering on top of the main content. I wish to have a water mark to the extreme left of screen and when it minimises it should either disappear or not have to be covering the main content.

This is the code that I currently worte:

```
<div id="background">
    <p id="bg-text">Add watermark here.</p>
</div>
//CSS:
#background{
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  background:white;
  top: 400px;
  left: 0px;
}

#bg-text
{
    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:10px;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Do not know why this is interfering with the main content. It should serve as watermark and disappear when not needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with Bootstrap breakpoints and display utility classes. Check out this link to learn more:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Try applying these display utility classes to your code. Using d-none will hide the div on mobile. The class d-md-block will then display this div on screen resolutions at and above medium size.

```
<div id="bg-text" class="d-none d-md-block">
    Add watermark here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To go responsive you'll have to get in touch with **media queries**.
Basically you have to define breakpoints for different screen sizes and also css code behind every breakpoint to tell your website how to behave reaching them.

[Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)
*(See comments and answers here)*

Comment: How do I justify my watermark to extreme left?
Is my CSS right? Because I do not think so.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w8Lxpaqv Maybe it will help you a bit. Basic idea is, to set background with fixed position and place your watermark with an absolute position to the left side.